# Получение WMSigner

Tags: php, webmoney

Здравствуйте.

Кто знает, где получить файл WMSigner и как далее получать с помощью него подпись (sign)?

Answer (score 2):

В данной документации описано как скомпилировать файл https://github.com/eagleas/wmsigner/blob/master/README.rus, лично не пробовал, но на будущее оставил для себя ссылку т.к. то же планирую подобную реализацию.

А вообще на официальном сайте Веб Мани можно посмотреть библиотеки для разных языков. https://wiki.webmoney.ru/projects/webmoney/wiki/WMSigner

Comment: Я это все видел. Не шврю, если честно, что и как компилировать. По поводу библиотек, так я хочу написать свой код в минимум строк.

Comment: Что бы реализовать в минимум строк думаю самым правильным решением будет смотреть их библиотеку и убрать всё лишнее что там есть. Лично для себя думаю что использование библиотеки весьма удобное и по сути не зависимо от Вашего кода, инициализация в любом случае не большая. Свой код получится не особо то меньше, во всяком случае лишний оверхед можно убрать, хотя смысла в этом особого я не вижу. Но для минимума строк нужно понять хотя бы на каком языке Вам нужна данная реализация.

Comment: Смотрел, тем куча бесполезных файлов, где я ничего не нашел.

Comment: На каком языке Вам нужно данное решение, и пробовали ли Вы использовать библиотеку, которую предлагает вебмани?

Comment: @ikerya хотелось бы поддержать предыдущего комментатора и поучаствовать в дискуссии. На сколько я понял - где получить и как подписать - понятно. Осталось понять, для чего Вам это нужно. Личный интересе для просто так? Работа с платежами? Интернет маркетинг? Было бы замечательно, если бы Вы отредактировали свой вопрос и дополнили его - описанием для чего Вам необходимо данное решение.

Comment: @Vayas решение нужно на php

Comment: @KonstantinMitjurin для проверки истории пользователя